# How do I build a lambda-based fluent builder?

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to create a Java fluent builder that is based on `java.util.Optional` to simplify my life

I would like to be able to call it like:

```
Person person = Optional.supply(Person::new)
                .with(Person::setName,"Andrew")
                .with(Person::setAge,32)
                .with(Person::setAddress,"10 Downing Street")
                .get();
```

In my example, I have called my new class Optional exactly as the original. In fact I copied its source code being unable to extend Optional.

I could implement the constructor

```
public static <T> Optional<T> supply(Supplier<T> supplier)
{
    T value = requireNonNull(supplier).get();
    return new Optional<T>(value);
}
```

But then I don't know how to implement the fluent setter. It should allow me setting a value in the held entity and return the optional *self*.

Setters are `Consumer`s of the type of the target property.

So how do I build my own fluent Optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little research I found that setters are just `BiConsumer`s of T and V where T is the entity type and V is the property type.

Whoever wants to build a fluent optional setter can use

```
public <H> Optional<T> with(BiConsumer<T, H> setter, H value)
{
    requireNonNull(setter);

    if (!isPresent())
        return empty();

    setter.accept(this.value, value);

    return this;
}
```

Sharing for posterity